# ASP.NET FormsAuthentication exclusive login

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I'm working on a website where I get a feed of usernames / hashed passwords from another service.  When someone sucesfully logs in I set a forms authentication cookie with [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx).

My client doesn't like multiple people logged with the same credentials.  They would like a log in to invalidate any currently logged in clients.

There isn't a method on FormsAuthentication to tell the server "invalidate any other cookie under this name".  [KB900111](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/900111) suggests the server doesn't maintain a list of valid cookies.  So my approach isn't sounding good.

What's the alternative?  Time to ditch forms auth?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025908/avoid-concurrent-login-logout-former-login-session-in-asp-net-membership http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303420/ensuring-only-one-user-login-using-asp-net-membership-provider   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937048/asp-net-membership-preventing-people-logging-in-as-the-same-user-on-different-mac

The trouble is that it's difficult to come up with good search terms for this.

Comment: You are right - i didn't come up with the right search terms to find the dupes.  My question is subtly different, as I want to kick out any 'other' logins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily. Forms auth still provides quite a bit of baked-in functionality you might want. Maybe you can generate and issue a Guid the first time each user logs in, and store that on the server-side, and in a cookie (security ticket preferably). Every time a request is made, you check to make sure the user is using not only the correct credentials, but also the same machine and browser (based on the cookie you issued the user when the user logged in). You would of course have to make sure that your Guid expires at some point, and also make sure you clear it out when the user signs out.

Comment: I'm following the guid serverside / cookie bit.  Where do I do the test for "same machine and browser"?

Comment: You could do it in a Global.asax.vb/.cs file in one of the events...I'd probably try the AuthenticateRequest event. This way every request would be validated and the validation can be controlled at a single location.